# php compare two arrays and order output by ref

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, listings

I have arrays order (list) by ref  :

```
$a = array('Blue', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow');
```

And new elements (mixing order + new element) :

```
$b = array('Orange', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Pink');
```

I want my outcome (`$b`) to be, like in `$a` order + new(s) element(s) :

```
Result : Array
 (
 [0] => Blue
 [1] => Red
 [2] => Orange
 [3] => Yellow
 [4] => Pink
 )
```

Any idea in language reference ?

Comment: Use `array_diff` to get the new elements in `$b`, and append them to `$a` to get the result.

Comment: Here it's so fast. Thanks all to help me, if i can help someone, i will do like Ace_Gentile. G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve array indexes doing $a + difference($b-a)

```
$a = array('Blue', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow');
$b = array('Orange', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Pink');

$merged = array_merge($a, array_diff($b, $a));
print_r($merged);
```

outputs

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Blue
        [1] => Red
        [2] => Orange
        [3] => Yellow
        [4] => Pink
    )
```

If you're not interested in keeping keys values  you can also use array_unique with an array_merge:

```
$merged = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b)));
print_r($merged);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blue
    [1] => Red
    [2] => Orange
    [3] => Yellow
    [8] => Pink
)
```

Comment: That doesn't necessarily preserve order. You need to use a combination of [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to get the results wanted.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: The OP does not mention anything about preserving order though.

Comment: From the question: "I want my outcome ($b) to be, like in $a order + new(s) element(s)"

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [*usort*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [*array_search*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) functions:

```
$a = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow'];
$b = ['Orange', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Pink'];

usort($b, function($x, $y) use ($a){
    $idx_x = array_search($x, $a);
    $idx_y = array_search($y, $a);
    if ($idx_x === false || $idx_y === false) return 1;
    return $idx_x - $idx_y;
});

print_r($b);
```

The output:
Array

```
(
    [0] => Blue
    [1] => Red
    [2] => Orange
    [3] => Yellow
    [4] => Pink
)
```